# TypeError: [function] is not a function in Passport local strategy

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate users locally with Passport.js while not keeping session and using my own JWTokens.

I was following this tutorial:
 [Learn using JWT with Passport authentication](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314)

While also reading Passport.js documentation. I don't know what went wrong, but passport doesn't seem to notice that some functions are indeed functions.

I've got a Load function to select a User from the DB(mongo) given certain criteria(a user might logIn with e-mail or phone number).

```
  load: function(options, cb) {
    options.select = options.select || 'email phone';
    return this.findOne(options.criteria)
      .select(options.select)
      .exec(cb);
  }
```

I'm calling passport.authenticate in my routes:

```
// Controllers //
const Users = require('../../app/controllers/users');  
...
...  
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/api/login' }), Users.login);
```

And here's my local strategy:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  {
  usernameField: 'email',
  phoneField: 'phone',
  passwordField: 'password',
  session: false
  }, 

  function(email, phone, password) {//cb == callback
    const options = {
      criteria: { email: email, phone: phone },
      select: 'name username email hashed_password salt'    
    };

    User.load(options, function(err, user) {

      if (err || !user){
        return res.status(400).json({
          type: 'failure',
          message: "User creation failed",  
          data: [err]
        });
      };

      if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          type: 'failure',
          message: "User creation failed",  
          data: [err]
        });
      };

      req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
         if (err) {
             res.send(err);
         }

         // generate a signed son web token with the contents of user object and return it in the response
         const token = jwt.sign(user.id, 'your_jwt_secret');
         return res.json({user, token});
      });
    });
  }
));
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: res.status is not a function
```

Before trying to get  stuff back from passport with responde. I was trying to do it with cb(callback), as done in the tutorial, but I keep getting the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with how you are implementing Passport's local strategy that are causing problems.

You are trying to use two fields as the username when Passport's local startegy only accepts one. (see: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/)

```
 function(username, password, done){}
```

If you want to use both as a username, you might want to consider creating your own custom strategy. This is going to be a little more in-depth, but you can start learning on the Passport Github page (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-strategy)

The second issue is that you are trying to get Passport to send a response in the local strategy which is not what it is intended to do. Instead, you should be passing the errors and return values to Passport's `done()` function, which will process them accordingly.

Here is an example of what your local strategy should look like:

```
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(async (email, phone, password, done) => {
        const options = {
            criteria: { email, phone },
            select: 'name username email hashed_password salt',
        };

        try {
            const user = await User.load(options);

            /**
             * If null is returned meaning there was no user found, send the done call
             * with the false flag. This tells passport to redirect to the failure URL.
             */
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false);
            }

            /**
             * If the user's password is incorrect, also return the done function with the false
             * flag. This tells passport to redirect to the failure URL.
             */
            if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
                return done(null, false);
            }

            /**
             * If a user is found and their password is verified, send the user object to
             * the done function. This will tell Passport to call the next middelware attaching
             * the user object.
             */
            return done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
            /**
             * If there is an error with the DB call, return generic message
             * for security purposes.
             */
            return done('There was an internal server error.');
        }
    })
);
```

and an example of what your load function should look like:

```
load: options => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        options.select = options.select || 'email phone';
        try {
            const user = await this.findOne(options.criteria)
                .select(options.select)
                .exec();

            resolve(user);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
};
```

As a general best practice, I changed your callbacks to the newer method of promises (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

This should work in the way you are intending to use Passport.